# Django ORM sync_to_async error FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: django, python-asyncio, python-3.7, django-orm

I am trying to implement Asynchronous support(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/) for Django ORM to write many records in Database(Postgres).

I am getting the ERROR:root:**FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections**

*I am creating coroutines add adding them to running the asyincio loop*

```
# Helper Class
class ModelsHelper:
    @staticmethod
    @sync_to_async
    def __handle_resource_data(data):
          // Some calculation to create kwargs dict
          return Resource.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
 
    async def store_data(metric):
        // some calculation to get data
        return await ModelsHelper.__handle_resource_data(data)
 
 
# Main File
def get_event_loop():
        loop = None
        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        except Exception as e:
            print(" New Event Loop ".center(50, '*'))
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        return loop
 
loop = get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(
            asyncio.gather(*[ModelsHelper.store_data(metric) for metric in metrics]),
                loop=loop
         )
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```